# The unique proper ideal in $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$ is maximal

Tags: abstract-algebra

The ring $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$ has a unique proper ideal, namely the ideal generated by $x+(x^2)$. How does it follow that this ideal is maximal? I know that the unique proper ideal is maximal provided it contains all non-units of the ring. Am I supposed to use this? I'm not sure how exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if $P(X)=a_nX^n+...+a_1X+a_0$ then 
$$P(X)+(X^2)=a_0+a_1X+ (X^2)$$

Moreover, if $a_0 \neq 0$ then 
$$\left( a_0+a_1X+ (X^2) \right)\left( a_0-a_1X+ (X^2) \right)=a_0^2 +(X^2)$$ is an unit in $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2)$.

It follows from here that all the non-invertible elements are in the ideal generated by $X+(X^2)$.

**P.S.** You can use this idea to prove the stronger statement that the only ideals in $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2)$ are $0+(X^2), X+(X^2)$ and $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2)$. If these are the three ideals, it is trivial to conclude that the only non-trivial one is maximal. This is what the problem is hinting towards.

Comment: Do you mean it is trivial to conclude that the only non-trivial ideal among the three you mentioned is maximal even without knowing the argument you provided? If so, why?

Comment: @user527831 If $R$ is a ring and $0, I, R$ are the only ideals, then $I$ is automatically maximal. That is because if $I \subseteq J$ is any ideal, $J$ can only be one in the list of ideals, and it cannot be the zero ideal.

Comment: So my statement in the question has the unnecessary assumption that the unique proper ideal must contain non-units? I guess there are two separate statements which I mixed. The first one is "if a ring contains a unique proper ideal, then this ideal is the unique maximal ideal", and the second one is "if a ring has a proper ideal containing all non-units of the ring, then this ideal is the unique maximal ideal". Is that correct?

Comment: @user527831 I would say that it is a bit more subtle. It is true that " a ring has an unique maximal ideal if and only if it has a proper ideal containing all non-units of the ring", and this is the standard way to prove that rings are local (i.e. has unique maximal ideal). Now, the assumption you made is that you must prove the problem by this standard method. In this particular case, there is a much faster way of proving this (the faster way works in this case, but only works very very rarely). This doesn't mean that the standard method doesn't work, it does. Is not that your approach is

Comment: incorrect, it is just that there exists a simpler solution in this case.

Comment: But the general statement (which works very very rarely) "if a ring $R$ has a unique proper ideal $I$ (i.e., there are only three ideals in $R$, namely $(0), I, R$), then $I$ is the unique maximal ideal" is also true, right? (By your previous comment.) And that's what you refer to as a simpler solution I guess.

Comment: @user527831 Yes. So, to sum it up, to prove that the ring in this problem is local, you have two possible approaches: 1) Prove that the non-units form an ideal or 2) Prove that $ x+(x^2)$ is the only non-trivial ideals. Note that in the second case you actually prove something stronger than "just one maximal ideal". Does this clarify it?

Comment: @user527831 Also note that there is a third possible approach, which is hinted in the previous answer: To prove that $I$ is maximal you can prove instead that $R/I$ is a field. Note that in the same style you can also prove that $x+(x^2)$ is the only non-trivial ideal: by one of the isomorphism theorems, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the ideals $I$ in $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2)$ and the ideals $J$ in $\mathbb R[X]$ containing $<X^2>$, and since $\mathbb R[X]$ is PID, you can connect thi to the monic divisors of $X^2$. The three ideals correspond to the three divisors $1,X,X^2$

Answer (score 4):

$\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)/(x/x^2) \cong \mathbb R[x]/(x) \cong \mathbb R$, where the first isomorphism is by the [third isomorphism theorem.](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Third_isomorphism_theorem)

This can be proven with your bare hands by taking $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2) \to \mathbb R[x]/(x)$ by $x \mapsto x$. consider the kernel of this map and apply the first isomorphism theorem?  The latter isomorphism is clear (I hope!)

Can you see why this is enough to conclude the result?

Comment: I don't understand what's the relation between the first isomorphism in the first paragraph (which follows from the third isomorphism theorem) and the isomorphism induced by the map you mention in the second paragraph. As far as I understand, the ideals $(x/x^2)$ and $(x+(x^2))$ of $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$ are different ideals. (Or they are not?)

Comment: You apply the first isomorphism theorem to the map in the first sentence of the second paragraph, which yields the first isomorphism in my answer.

Comment: $(x/x^2)$ denotes here the ideal $(\,x+(x^2)\,)$ in $\Bbb R^2[x]/(x^2)$.

Comment: @Berci yes of course. Am I missing something here?